# Laravel route middleware outputting my log

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to run some middleware on my routes via my package's service provider before the routes run in my Laravel project but I'm not seeing my `var_dump` despite running `php artisan route:list` showing that the `BeforeMiddleware` is applied. Am I using the wrong middleware?

My service provider:

```
<?php

namespace Company\FudgeInboundManagementBridge;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Company\FudgeInboundManagementBridge\Http\Middleware\BeforeMiddleware;

class FudgeInboundManagementBridgeServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerFiles();
    }

    /**
     * Register files
     */
    protected function registerFiles(): void
    {
        Route::middleware(BeforeMiddleware::class)->group(function () {
            $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/routes/fudge-routes.php');
        });

        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__ . '/config/FudgeInboundManagementBridge.php' => config_path('FudgeInboundManagementBridge.php'),
        ], 'config');
    }
}
```

My middleware:

```
<?php

namespace Company\FudgeInboundManagementBridge\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BeforeMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        var_dump('hello from before middleware - bridge');
        die;
        // return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Seems like it's not triggering?

Comment: Shouldn't middleware trigger only on request and not on listing requests through console?

Comment: I need to run the middleware before each route in `fudge-routes` so that I can perform an action, such as removing.a cookie from the webpage. I'd hope to see my var_dump when going to any of my routes in that file before the routes file runs

Comment: Try using `Log::info` instead of `var_dump`. That will log it to a file inside of `storage/files`

Comment: Just tried that, the file isn't being created, no errors.

Comment: ok, This is not probably the best solution, but can you check with dd function? like dd('here')? and maybe "php artisan route:clear" command can be helpful.